# Taking a screenshot using Virtual DOM does not work

Tags: html2canvas

Taking a screenshot using Virtual DOM does not work.

Error:

```
html2canvas.min.js:20 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Document is not attached to a Window
    at html2canvas.min.js:20:193237
    at html2canvas.min.js:20:1976
    at Object.next (html2canvas.min.js:20:2081)
    at html2canvas.min.js:20:1023
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at a (html2canvas.min.js:20:774)
    at Vs (html2canvas.min.js:20:192912)
    at html2canvas.min.js:20:196186
    at takeScreenShot (set style [modal].html:94:7)
    at action (set style [modal].html:68:11)
```

Code:

```
 let htmlString = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
 let virtualDom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");
 html2canvas(virtualDom.body).then((canvas) => {
       let base64image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      });
```

Specifications:

1. html2canvas version tested with: html2canvas 1.4.0
2. Browser &
   version: Google Chrome & Version 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build)
   (64-bit)

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working using `iframe`, as suggested by [wuyuedefeng](https://github.com/wuyuedefeng) in [this response on GitHub](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/2794#issuecomment-1068664022):

> ```js
> async htmlTextToCanvas(htmlText) {
>     const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
>     iframe.style.width = '0px'
>     iframe.style.overflow = 'hidden'
>     document.body.appendChild(iframe)
>     iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
>     iframe.contentWindow.document.write(htmlText)
>     iframe.contentWindow.document.close()
>     const dom = iframe.contentWindow.document.body
>     
>     //const dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(`<div>111</div>`, "text/xml").firstChild
>     const canvas = await html2canvas(dom).finally(() => {
>       iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe)
>     })
>     return canvas
>   }
> ```